# How to fix rangeerror in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm using a package call alphabet_list_scroll_view 2.0.0 in my flutter project.

I'm using the example code from their [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/alphabet_list_scroll_view/example) but I'm getting

```
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
```

for some reason. I'm trying to add itemCount right above itemBuilder but I'm getting the parameter is not existed.

Any help would be really appreciated with dummy/mock list..

Here is part of the code from the example code that they provided.

```
class _AboutScreenState extends State<AboutScreen> {
  List<User> userList = [];
  List<String> strList = ['Ja', 'bo', 'Ce', 'Do', 'Ha', 'Tu', 'Zu'];
  List<Widget> favouriteList = [];
  List<Widget> normalList = [];
  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
      ),
      body: AlphabetListScrollView(
        strList: strList,
        highlightTextStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.yellow,
        ),
        showPreview: true,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return normalList[index];
        },
        indexedHeight: (i) {
          return 80;
        },
        keyboardUsage: true,
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are populating the `normalList` but using on `itemBuilder`. You can do it on initState to solve this error.

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    for (final item in strList) {
      normalList.add(Text(item));
    }
  }
```

And itemcount isnt a valid key in alphabet list scroll view

Comment: Thank Yeasin. I don't get the error anymore and I can see the list but any idea why the List is not scrolling when I hover a letter that is on the right side?

Comment: Not sure about the right scrollable issue. but on left scroll is working. It is not build for windows, maybe this is the issue on hover. Also, one thing on documentation about filter case. And this package last updated Published 16 months ago

Comment: Hi bro, I use a different package instead but I'm getting an error when I try to hookup with my actual json file so I would be really appreciated if I can get your hlep again in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73185638/how-to-fix-not-a-subtype-error-in-flutter